# Linear search vs binary search real time performance in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, binary-search, linear-search

Getting totally unexpected results while comparing binary search vs linear search's real time performance in C++ using the code below  -

```
typedef std::chrono::microseconds us;

int linear_search(uint64_t* val, int s, int e, uint64_t k) {
    while (s < e) {
      if (!less<uint64_t>()(val[s], k)) {
        break;
      }
      ++s;
    }
    return {s};
}

int binary_search(uint64_t* val, int s, int e, uint64_t k) {
    while (s != e) {
      const int mid = (s + e) >> 1;
      if (less<uint64_t>()(val[mid], k)) {
        s = mid + 1;
      } else {
        e = mid;
      }
    }
    return {s};
}


int main() {

    // Preparing data
    int iter = 1000000;
    int m = 1000;
    uint64_t val[m];
    for(int i = 0; i < m;i++) {
        val[i] = rand();
    }
    sort(val, val + m);
    uint64_t key = rand();

    // Linear search time computation
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
        linear_search(val, 0, m - 1, key);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<us>(end - start);
    std::cout << "Linear search: " << m << " values "
              << elapsed_us.count() << "us\n";

    // Binary search time computation
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
        binary_search(val, 0, m - 1, key);
    }
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    elapsed_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<us>(end - start);
    std::cout << "Binary search: " << m <<" values "
              << elapsed_us.count() << "us\n";
}
```

Compiling without optimisation, getting following output -

```
Linear search: 1000 values 1848621us
Binary search: 1000 values 24975us
```

When compiled with -O3 optimisation, getting this output -

```
Linear search: 1000 values 0us
Binary search: 1000 values 13424us
```

I understand that for small array size, binary search may be expensive than linear but can't understand reason for difference of this magnitude by adding -O3

Comment: optimized away, do something with the output so the compiler will not skip the block completely

Comment: you are not using the result of the linear search, hence the compiler removes that part when optimizations are turned on, the puzzling part is rather why the same is not happening to the binary search part

Comment: I recommend [the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) which lets you see the generated assembly code to see what's happening.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 val is taken by pointer, the compiler cannot exclude side effect if the variable is referenced after, binary search is last and no reference to val are present after it.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi well yes, but no.The compiler does optimize `linear_search` which comes first, both use the pointer. Once it does optimize `linear_search` it could as well remove `binary_search`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 wow, comfirmation bias in action, I read what I was expecting to read! That's puzzling indeed.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi, also the result doesn't change if I change the order of linear_search and binary_search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I benchmarked your code with https://quick-bench.com and binary search is much faster (for `m = 100`, it breaks for `m = 1000`). That's my benchmark code:

```
int linear_search(uint64_t* val, int s, int e, uint64_t k) {
    while (s < e) {
      if (!std::less<uint64_t>()(val[s], k)) {
        break;
      }
      ++s;
    }
    return s;
}

int binary_search(uint64_t* val, int s, int e, uint64_t k) {
    while (s != e) {
      const int mid = (s + e) >> 1;
      if (std::less<uint64_t>()(val[mid], k)) {
        s = mid + 1;
      } else {
        e = mid;
      }
    }
    return s;
}

constexpr int m = 100;
uint64_t val[m];
uint64_t key = rand();
void init() {
  static bool isInitialized = false;
  if (isInitialized) return;
  for(int i = 0; i < m;i++) {
    val[i] = rand();
  }
  std::sort(val, val + m);
  isInitialized = true;
}

static void Linear(benchmark::State& state) {
  init();
  for (auto _ : state) {
    int result = linear_search(val, 0, m - 1, key);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Linear);

static void Binary(benchmark::State& state) {
  init();
  for (auto _ : state) {
    int result = binary_search(val, 0, m - 1, key);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Binary);
```

and the result:

[image]

Only the code inside `for (auto _ : state) {` is benchmarked.

Comment: Didn't know about benchmarks. Thanks for the updated code !

Answer (score 2):

The compiler manages to realize that your linear search is a noop (it has no side effects) and converts it to doing nothing.  So it takes zero time.

To fix that, consider taking the return value and adding it up, then printing it outside the timing block.